# Need formula to Detect "Different products" for same ID IN EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, difference, excel-tables

I'll need a formula in excel to detect for example 1111; has three different products linked, meanwhile 2222 has only linked "oranges"

Here I left and example of my excel table:

| Product ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1111 | Apples |
| 1111 | Orange |
| 1111 | Grapes |
| 2222 | Orange |
| 3333 | Apples |
| 3333 | Orange |
| 3333 | Grapes |
| 4444 | Orange |

Hope it is clear!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: concatenate them together then count.

Comment: If i concatenate eg: 1111- Apple, 1111-Orange, 1111-Grapes and then i do a countIf it will throw a 1 in each row, Ill need a formula to give me the info that "product id" has 3,4....n products linked to it. Sry if i dont explain myself correctly.

Comment: @JoseCJ Try using this formula, it shall give you the expected output `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"&B2)+1` Assuming `A1` & `B1` is header, so place the formula in cell `C2`

Comment: If column B contains unique values a count if on column A only would suffice even.

Comment: @JoseCJ just to make it look fancy you may use this as well, `="Product ID "&A2&"-Product Type No.-"&COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"&B2)+1`

Comment: Thx @MayukhBhattacharya trying i think its working must do some testing as B has duplicates values too, i explain my self i could have several 1111 - apples row.

Comment: @JoseCJ so did you try the one as suggested ? Or do you need a screenshot for the example!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya appreciate the screenshot if possible!

Comment: @JoseCJ Done, I hope it makes sense, !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing just for clarity, refer image below,

• Formula used in cell `C2`

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"&B2)+1
```

• Formula used in cell `D2` --> You may use this as well or modify to make it look bit fancy

```
="Product ID "&A2&"-Product Type No.-"&COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"&B2)+1
```

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

Comment: Thanks it actually does! :)

Comment: @JoseCJ Glad you are able to work it out, thank you for sharing the feedback as well!

Comment: it seems when i have a pair repeated, EG 1111- apple 2/3 times it does not gives consistent info. The final objective is to identify which "product IDs" have 1 product associated and which one have more than 1 product associated. If i have two times 1111- apples it will have only 1 product even the same row is repeated, sry if im not explaining myself .... :(

Comment: @JoseCJ so you mean to say if there is 3 1111 & 3 apple then it would show 1 for once and the rest will be empty or like it should show as 1,2,3?

Comment: The first one, like you said if 1111+appple is reapeated three times i want to show 1, and if then a new row contains 1111+orange then this new one shows a 2 instead.

Comment: @JoseCJ alright understood now give me a moment sharing soon

Comment: tons of thanks !

Comment: @JoseCJ try this `=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,1,IF(B2=B1,C1,C1+1))`

Comment: C column cell should contain this formula right ? =COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2,A2,$B$2:$B2,"<>"&B2)+1

Comment: @JoseCJ No, use the new one, also note the new formula works when the range is a sorted one.!

Comment: when using this one my "C COLUMN" is empty I just have A - Product Id / B - Product name =IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,1,IF(B2=B1,C1,C1+1))

Comment: @JoseCJ can you share a onedrive link here in comments of your excel workbook?

Comment: i was idiot missing a "." in formula. All working know!

Comment: @JoseCJ thank you very much for sharing the feedback sir!

Comment: Any way to upvote or something? Almost first time here. Much appreciate your time & your solution!

Comment: @JoseCJ its okay, you cant upvote now, unless you have 15 rep, so you have already accepted the same an answer, thats fine and thank you!